# 1990s sci-fi tv show with invading humanoids and dull crosshatched eyes

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I am remembering a sci fi TV show from probably around the 90s in which the enemies had strange eyes. The eyes were dull and had either a cross or a line through them. 
Weaponry was like assault rifles, maybe energy based, maybe bullets, but looking basically along the lines of special forces assault teams (along the lines of SG-1 type weaponry).

I think humans could be converted some how, similar to the Borg of *Star Trek* and the eyes were the way to tell if someone was human or not.

I want to say it was titled something like *EarthX* or *Earth3000* or something like that, but I've tried Googling those with no results, so that is probably wrong.

EDITS:

- This was in the US. I'm not sure of the channel or syndication, but at the time I know we only had ABC, CBS, NBC, FOX and PBS. I'm pretty sure it wasn't on PBS.
- I'm not sure of any 'in universe' planet names.
- This was live-action, not anime.
- Aliens were humanoid and looked normal, except for the eyes.
- Overall 'look' of the show was dark and industrial futuristic, not the clean, white futuristic look.
- Few, if any, special effects
- Seemed aimed at adults, no comic 'barney the dinosaur' style characters or similar. Definitely more like SG-1 than anything else I can think of (minus the actual Stargate of course)

Comment: Can you include information like what country this was in, whether it was syndicated or on a major network, or anything else along that line?

Comment: Having searched http://www.imdb.com/tv/ and http://thetvdb.com/ there is no TV show with the word "earth" in the title from 1980 to 2000 that fits.

Comment: Could this have been an episode from `The Outer Limits`?

Comment: I have been trying to find out about a similar TV show! I have a vague memory of watching a series about humans on an alien planet (or the other way round) where they were driving around in 4WDs and there was acid rain etc....it is really bugging me!!! I don't think it was star trek or anything.

Comment: I don't know if this can help you out, but here's a [List of science fiction television programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_television_programs) that could give you some insights of the TV Show name (or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is [Space: Above and Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt).

> The Earth is embroiled in a desperate war against alien invaders, and this series focuses on one squadron of Marine pilots involved in it.

David Duchovny played such a character called Handsome Al who was a silicate (an artificial humanoid that was designed to fight in a war but turned on the humans)

Comment: Here's a [link](http://johnkennethmuir.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/cult-tv-flashback-102-space-above-and-beyond-rr/) about the show, with a picture of Duchovny's weird eyes more than halfway down.

Comment: That series had some interesting ideas and a couple of good shows - the one with William Sadler as a beyond-the-edge pilot with a taste for Johnny Cash music is a lesser-known classic.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be [Earth: Final Conflict](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123816/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) from 1997, this is the plot summary from IMDb:

> An androgynous alien species called the Taelons arrive on earth,
>   claiming to be companions of humanity, putting an end to crime,
>   illness, and famine. Some are suspicious of the Taleons, and form a
>   resistance movement. The resistance soon learned that the force that
>   sustains the Taelons are breaking down, and they are using humans as
>   test subjects in experiments to help save their species. The initial
>   focus of the show was Commander William Boone and his partner, Captain
>   Lili Marquette, who worked for both the Taelons and the resistance.
>   After Boone was killed, the show introduced a new protagonist, Major
>   Liam Kincaid, and began to play on the strengths of it's ensemble
>   cast.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's it. The aliens were humanoid, but no makeup (other than maybe a bit of paleness), so the Taelons aren't right. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: I don't remember anything about infected humans being distinguishable by their eyes, but the Borg-like conversion of humans took place in the 5th season, when the Taelons had been replaced by the "Atavus".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atavus


http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqd4_B0iMOE

If you want to see if that's the show you're looking for, check season 5.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Invasion Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0140743/) (1998) TV series. The alien was humanoid with dark cat like eyes.

Comment: No, but the atmosphere of that show is a lot closer to what I am remembering. Thanks for helping though.